# Where does it say that 0x prefix makes literals hex base?

Tags: python, pep

I know that I can write `0x1230FF` in Python and it will be a literal int with the value  1192191. But I can't find anything in the official docs or the PEPs that specifies that this is allowed and that `0x` indeed denotes a hex radix.

The closest I could find was [PEP-3127 Integer Literal Support and Syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127), which mostly talks about octal and binary. It makes some interesting suggestions like

> Suggestions were made to use a "c" (the second letter of "oCtal"), or even to use a "t" for "ocTal" and an "n" for "biNary" to go along with the "x" for "heXadecimal".

Can somebody provide a link to an official specification of this?

Note that I am not talking about string formatting, but syntax for Number literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals

specify that a hexadecimal integer literal is made up of an `0` followed by an `x` or `X`, followed by one or more hexadecimal digits and underscores.

> ```
> hexinteger   ::=  "0" ("x" | "X") (["_"] hexdigit)+
> ```